# Maven GWT Plugin - generateAsync and Generic type

Tags: gwt, maven, gwt-maven-plugin

Hi there I successfully installed the GWT Maven plugin and it generates on incremental save the Async RPC services.

However I got a little problem, if I use :

`ArrayList<Whatever>` then the Async class generated will have a method `AsyncCallback<java.util.ArrayList> callback`

As you can see it's missing the `<Whatever>` reference, I'm almost certain that one day I saw it work.

Here are the version I use:
Maven 3.0.4
MavenGwtPlugin 2.4.0
QDox 1.2
GWT 2.4.0

I tried QDox 2.0-snapshot as read on one forum thread, nothing is working.

If you got an idea !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-315

Make sure you only run `genericAsync` from a clean build.

Comment: Ok thanks, I had to replace the generation on incremental build with an eclipse run : `clean gwt:generateAsync install`. It's a bit longer but we won't create interfaces every 10 minutes anyway. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I can't begin to count the number of times I've had to come to SO to find an answer from you Thomas on how to work around some problem with the gwt-maven-plugin. It was fun at first, but now its just frustrating the number of esoteric problems it has. For instance, right out of the box the archetype doesn't add the lifecycle mappings which probably stymies everyone who tries to use it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: don't use the archetype from the plugin itself, it does more harm than good. I think I'll remove it for the next version.